# How to programmatically get a graph in Google Sheets as an image

Tags: charts, google-sheets, google-api, publish

Using Google Sheets API, is there an easy way to get a graph from within the sheet as an image file?  I want to display the graph somewhere else and would rather not recreate the graph using the data from the sheet.

Comment: You want to retrieve the chart as an image using a script. If my understanding is correct, can I ask you about the language you want to use?

Comment: use the `getAs(contentType)` [method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart#getAs(String))...

Answer (score 0):

you could download it or publish it so API should support this as well:

[image]

Comment: The link that gets created by publishing the chart is exactly what I need, but is there a way to do this programmatically?  I am not seeing anything in the Google Sheets API about this.